# Unable to install tezos binaries - Debian

Tags: node

I guess the bottomline question: is there a way install the tezos binaries on Debian as described at https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html; in other words

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:serokell/tezos && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-client
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-node
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-baker-012-psithaca
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-accuser-012-psithaca
```

or do the above steps only work on Ubuntu and I will need to compile from OPAM or use Docker images?

I'm on Debian 10 (buster) and keep getting this error when I try to install the client

```
$ sudo apt install tezos-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tezos-client
```

This is in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/serokell-ubuntu-tezos-jammy.list file (after some manual updates)

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu jammy main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu jammy main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of commands that should work for Debian is similar to the one [described for Raspberry Pis](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/blob/master/docs/distros/ubuntu.md#raspberry) (because their OS is Debian-based too).

In your specific case of Debian 10 (buster) it should be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu bionic main'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 37B8819B7D0D183812DCA9A8CE5A4D8933AE7CBB
sudo apt-get update
```

after which you can install as usual, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-client
```

Note that the first command above uses `bionic`, but this won't work for all Debian versions, which is why often using PPAs on Debian is discouraged, as PPAs are intended to work with Ubuntu releases.

Your mileage may vary, but I suggest to check out [this `askubuntu` thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/what-debian-version-are-the-different-ubuntu-versions-based-on/445496#445496) on the names of matching releases and the [`tezos-packaging` support policy](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/blob/master/docs/support-policy.md#ubuntu-packages) to pick your best option (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the binaries from the tezos CI/CD pipeline.

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/jobs/2304146265/artifacts/browse/tezos-binaries

The binaries above are from the latest release: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/tags/v12.3